# How to draw rectangle over a plot?

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

Is it possible to draw rectangle using OxyPlot? Something like
[image]:

or does OxyPlot not support this?

Comment: How did you draw this horizontal orange  line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed.

There's a couple of ways you can do it. I would prefer to use an annotation as this will also give you a highlighted background and give you the option to add click events on this area. There's probably a way to remove the highlight if you want to make it look like the image you've provided.

```
var Event = new PolygonAnnotation();

Event.Layer = AnnotationLayer.BelowAxes;
Event.StrokeThickness = 5;
Event.Stroke = OxyColor.FromRgb(0, 0, 255);
Event.LineStyle = LineStyle.Automatic;

Event.Points.Add(new DataPoint(X, Y));
Event.Points.Add(new DataPoint(X, Y));            
Event.Points.Add(new DataPoint(X, Y));
Event.Points.Add(new DataPoint(X, Y));
```

Another more simplistic way is to create a line series and give it the corners of your rectangle.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use RectangleAnnotation which is already there?
It provides fill , stroke , click detection , text.
Example :

```
model.Annotations.Add(new RectangleAnnotation { MinimumX = 20, MaximumX = 70, MinimumY = 10, MaximumY = 40, TextRotation = 10, Text = "RectangleAnnotation", Fill = OxyColor.FromAColor(99, OxyColors.Blue), Stroke = OxyColors.Black, StrokeThickness = 2 });
```

You can always create your own custom annotations if existing are not good enough.

Comment: Is there a way to draw a RectangleAnnotation with Rounded Corner ?

Comment: With custom annotation any shape can be drawn. OxyPlot is very flexible and can be easily extended. OxyPlot source code includes  examples of custom annotation.