# Screen / window coordinate of a point in OxyPlot

Tags: oxyplot

I am using OxyPlot to draw a smooth curve using some input points. I now want to paint the background of the plot depending on the curve. e.g. The rectangle where the curve is below a certain y-value should be painted red, and if it above another specific y-value, the background should be painted green.
For this, I would need some way to get the screen coordinate for any point on the OxyPlot curve? Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe the [examples](http://resources.oxyplot.org/examplebrowser/) or this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780154/how-to-draw-rectangle-over-a-plot) will help you.